# how to inject dependency outside activity or fragment in Kodein or Koin?

Tags: android, kodein

want to initialize interface in a non activity or fragment class with Kodein DI Android

sample shows only hot to use Kodein inside activity, but not on the other parts

```
 class MainViewModel() :  KodeinAware{
   override val kodein by closestKodein()
   val repository : Repository by instance()
 }
```

in activity it works, but in other classes it shows error.
I want to initialize interface inside another class

Comment: If you are using Android ViewModel, then I suppose `MainViewModel` should extend `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

`closestKodein` only works in Android `Context` aware classes (such as fragments & activities).
To use it outside of these classes, you need an Android `context`.

The android documentation clearly states:

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.
>
> [...]
>
> If the ViewModel needs the Application context, for example to find a system service, it can extend the [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) class and have a constructor that receives the Application in the constructor, since Application class extends Context.

Therefore, to access Kodein from a ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(app: Application) : ApplicationViewModel(app), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein = app.kodein
    val repository : Repository by instance()
}
```

Comment: but I can not send context to ViewModel

Comment: I've edited the answer to be specific to Android ViewModel. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simpy pass a context or activity as param

```
override val kodein by closestKodein(context)
```

More info https://kodein.org/Kodein-DI/?5.0/android#_getting_a_kodein_object

Answer (score 1):

Use it in any place. `appKodein` is global function.

```
val dataLayer: DataLayer = appKodein().instance()
```

Answer (score 0):

`override val kodein by kodein(activity!!)`

Answer (score 0):

```
class ReportViewModel(context: Context):ViewModel() ,KodeinAware
{
override val kodein by kodein(context)
val reportRepository:ReportRepository by instance()
}
```

My answer